# create an image beside a text with minus margin CSS

Tags: html, css

Im newbie in CSS so please bear with me.

Im trying to create this design with CSS :

[image]

The image is not simply floating at left of the text. The image is taller than the text and it has a little minus `margin-top`.

However, i have 2 problems :

1. When i tried to use margin-top, the image is moving up, but the moving part is cropped.
2. I cant make the text shorter than the image. It always follow the image's height.

And **i need to use %** which make things more complicated for me.

**EDIT**
This is the html :

```
<li class="box">
<img class="picture" src="images/HotPromo/tagPhoto1.png"/>
<p class="name"><b>Name</b></p>
<p class="location"></p>
<p class="hidden"></p>
</li>
```

And this is the CSS :

```
#listHotPromo{
    background: #c4a76e;
    margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 3%;
    /*show background*/
    overflow: auto;
}

.box{
    background: #e8c07a;
    margin: 5% 5% 10% 5%;
    border-radius: 3%;
    /*show background*/
    overflow: auto;
}

.box img {
    float:left;
    width: 30%;
}

.box p {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Any help is appreciated and please ask me if you need something.

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Please edit your HTML and css.

Comment: you need to add the image in absolute position, if you share the html/css code that will be better for us.

Comment: ok edited, please help me out :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot:

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.image {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="images/your-image-here.png" alt="" title="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course, all of that is simply an example, you will need to modify to suit your needs.  But if you use the position: relative for the text part wrapper, and have position: absolute for the image itself, it will overlay the text and you can put the image wherever you like using the top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; properties.

Let me know if that helps ;)

EDIT:

HTML:

```
<div id="listHotPromo">
    <div class="box">
        <img src="images/your-image-here.png" alt="" title="" />
        <p><b>Name</b></p>
        <p>Post Location Here</p>
        <p>Post phone number here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#listHotPromo{
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 5%;
    background: #c4a76e;
    border-radius: 3%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.box{
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    margin:  0 auto;
    background: #e8c07a;
    border-radius: 3%;
    position: relative;
    top: 23px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.box img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: -20px;
}
.box p {
    width: 350px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
}
```

And here is the example as a link you can view: http://jsfiddle.net/6rUrW/

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your code helped me, but its still not working until now. The image is still cropped. Please see the code i provided in my question, maybe you can help me :D

Comment: Please review my edit above ;)  This should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks very much! I really appreciate your help. Its too bad i only can upvote once :D

Answer (score 1):

you can try this approach:

- the image is positioned absolute.
- the container of the image and text must have a padding left more
  than or equal to the size of the image.
- the text is in normal position.
- use a negative margin for positioning the image.

  with the setup of the markup, positioning of the image would be easy.

`

```
        #divContainer {
            padding-left: 40px;
            display: block
        }
        #myImg {
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: -35px;
        }
```

`

```
    <div id="divContainer">
            <img  id="myImg" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5ae9a98711b2ceeeadf7a25175f19382?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG"/>
             <span id="MySpan">
                <b>PrimaryText</b>
                        <p>SecondaryText</p>
            </span>
          </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I still cant do accomplish it. Please see my edited question, i put some code there.

Comment: i noticed in the markup:


 -you should place your all your <p>sometext</p> into one container.to make it segregated.
 
 
 -what actually grows is the container the .box class. it adjust based on the size of your image.

Comment: "When i tried to use margin-top, the image is moving up, but the moving part is cropped."   
 ->  -your image with the current setup seems to be cut when it has a negative margin. it is because the container's position is relative.

Comment: "I cant make the text shorter than the image. It always follow the image's height."
 -> it is not the text that follows the height. but the container itself. try to add background color to the text so that you will be able to see.